# Left join after a into group in Linq using entity framework (core)

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Problem: I would like to generate the exact sql below in the desired output using linq syntax (Entity framework 7)

***The goal of the question is to generate the exact sql below!***
**Desired Output**

```
select a.AppUserId, u.Email, a.FirstName, a.MiddleName, a.LastName, a.IsInternal, a.AspNetUserId, a.PictureLink, a.SignatureLink, a.PhoneNumber, a.Extension, a.FaxNumber, a.MobileNumber, a.Skype, r.Name as 'Role', a.SupervisorId, a.BackUpId, a.HasAutoAssignClaims, a.IsActive
from AppUser a
join AspNetUsers u on a.AspNetUserId = u.Id
left join AspNetUserRoles ur on u.Id = ur.UserId
left join AspNetRoles r on ur.RoleId = r.Id
```

I have only being able to get the exact same sql but with inner joins. I can't seem to get the two left joins. The code below here how I was able to generate the inner joins and also a fail attempt at generating the left joins.

```
SELECT [a].[AppUserId], [a].[FirstName], [a].[MiddleName], [a].[LastName], [a].[IsInternal], [a].[AspNetUserId], [a].[PictureLink], [a].[SignatureLink], [a].[PhoneNumber], [a].[Extension], [a].[FaxNumber], [a].[MobileNumber], [a].[Skype], [a].[SupervisorId], [a].[BackUpId], [a].[HasAutoAssignClaims], [a].[IsActive]
FROM [AppUser] AS [a]
INNER JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [b] ON [a].[AspNetUserId] = [b].[Id]
INNER JOIN [AspNetUserRoles] AS [c] ON [b].[Id] = [c].[UserId]
INNER JOIN [AspNetRoles] AS [d] ON [a].[RoleId] = [d].[Id]
```

## Code with inner join works but I want left joins....:

```
 var query = (
                              //INNER JOIN 
                              from a in _dbCtx.AppUser
                              join b in _dbCtx.Users
                              on a.AspNetUserId equals b.Id 


                              ////LEFT JOIN
                              join c in _dbCtx.UserRoles
                              on b.Id equals c.UserId 

                              //    //    //LEFT JOIN  (if you wanted right join the easiest way is to flip the order of the tables. 
                              join d in _dbCtx.Roles
                              on a.RoleId equals d.Id





                          select new
                          {
                              AppUserId = a.AppUserId,
                              //Email = b.Email,
                              FirstName = a.FirstName,
                              MiddleName = a.MiddleName,
                              LastName = a.LastName,
                              IsInternal = a.IsInternal,
                              AspNetUserId = a.AspNetUserId,
                              PictureLink = a.PictureLink,
                              SignatureLink = a.SignatureLink,
                              PhoneNumber = a.PhoneNumber,
                              Extension = a.Extension,
                              FaxNumber = a.FaxNumber,
                              MobileNumber = a.MobileNumber,
                              Skype = a.Skype,
                              //Role = d.Name != null ? string.Empty :d.Name ,
                              SupervisorId = a.SupervisorId,
                              BackUpId = a.BackUpId,
                              HasAutoAssignClaims = a.HasAutoAssignClaims,
                              IsActive = a.IsActive

                          }).ToList();
```

## Code with Left Join...which I am missing some concept doesnt work

what doesnt work is that on g2.RoleId equals d.Id into group3 line the g2 is not available. So how would I make c.RoleId available for my next left join? Basically after you group something you can no longer use it apparently.

```
        var LeftJoin= (
                          //INNER JOIN 
                          from a in _dbCtx.AppUser
                          join b in _dbCtx.Users
                          on a.AspNetUserId equals b.Id 


                          ////LEFT JOIN
                          join c in _dbCtx.UserRoles
                          on b.Id equals c.UserId into group2
                          from g2 in group2.DefaultIfEmpty() //makes it left join 



                          join d in _dbCtx.Roles
                          on g2.RoleId equals d.Id into group3
                          from g3 in group3.DefaultIfEmpty()

                          select new
                          {
                              AppUserId = a.AppUserId,
                              Email = b.Email,
                              FirstName = a.FirstName,
                              MiddleName = a.MiddleName,
                              LastName = a.LastName,
                              IsInternal = a.IsInternal,
                              AspNetUserId = a.AspNetUserId,
                              PictureLink = a.PictureLink,
                              SignatureLink = a.SignatureLink,
                              PhoneNumber = a.PhoneNumber,
                              Extension = a.Extension,
                              FaxNumber = a.FaxNumber,
                              MobileNumber = a.MobileNumber,
                              Skype = a.Skype,
                              Role = g3.Name != null ? string.Empty :g3.Name ,
                              SupervisorId = a.SupervisorId,
                              BackUpId = a.BackUpId,
                              HasAutoAssignClaims = a.HasAutoAssignClaims,
                              IsActive = a.IsActive

                          }).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: You should elaborate on this: `some concept doesnt work`

Comment: I elaborated that g2.RoleId is no longer available when i use on g2.RoleId equals d.Id into group3. The overall goal is to replicate the query above with the left joins in whatever methodology.

Comment: What do you mean by *not available*? Syntactically, this looks like a correct statement.

Comment: It give an exception the sequence has no elements. That is because after you group them it is not longer available to be invoked.

Comment: Your `LeftJoin` query is correct. In EF6 it generates exactly what you expect (as it should). In EF7 (core) it just doesn't work, and the same applies to many other valid queries, so I would say EF7 is just not ready to be used yet.

Comment: Thank you so much for letting me know that I am really happy that my syntax would work on ef6 i was pulling my hair. I will switch to ef 6 and see if the query works.

Comment: Bingo! https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3629

Answer (score 4):

*In case anyone comes to this question, thinking it hasn't been answered, the answer is currently buried in a comment chain after the question. I'm merely paraphrasing the key comments here.*

The problem is that Entity Framework 7 is currently a [release candidate](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.Commands/7.0.0-rc1-final) and has some bugs. One of these bugs ([Left Join doesn't work if the filter is composed on top](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/3629)) is causing the failure of the left join noted by the OP.

The solution, for now, is to revert to Entity Framework 6, or temporarily use a stored procedure or inline SQL until the bug is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

If i understood you properly you problem is that EF is not generating LEft join. If yes then solution is pretty simple your Entities should have nullable property for instance

```
 public class SomeClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int? CategoryId { get; set; }
        public Category Category {get;set:}
    }
```

One option which is in my head

```
_dbCtx.SqlQuery<T>(SqlStringHEre).ToList()
```

Other option, and aspnet tables i would do it differently

```
var query = _dbCtx.AppUser
.Include(apu=>apu.AspNetUser)
.Include(apu=>apu.AspNetUser.Roles)
.Include(apu=>apu.AspNetUser.Roles.Select(r=>r.Role))
.ToList();
```

but here is problem as we talk in comments that IdentityUserRole does not have refference to role so lets fix that.
 create class

```
 public class UserToRole : IdentityUserRole<int>
    {
        public Role Role { get; set; }
    }
```

Then extend your user class

```
 public class YourUser : IdentityUser<int, IdentityUserLogin<int>, UserToRole, IdentityUserClaim<int>>
```

Now you can do what you want

```
_db.Users.Select(u=>u.Roles.Select(r=>r.Role.Name))
```

Comment: Unfortunately that generates sql not equivalent to my query above. Which also does not contain the role name very important in the query. It also is not the best sql. Remember what I want is to generate the exact sql I posed above in the question.   SELECT [a].[UserId], [a].[RoleId]
FROM [AspNetUserRoles] AS [a]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM [AppUser] AS [apu]
INNER JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [a] ON [apu].[AspNetUserId] = [a].[Id]
INNER JOIN [AspNetUsers] AS [a0] ON [apu].[AspNetUserId] = [a0].[Id]
ORDER BY [a].[Id]

Comment: @hidden can you explain why you need exact same query?

Comment: because i cant believe it is not possible to generate a simple left join...I got the inner join equivalent why is it so hard to do a simple left join.

Comment: If you need that exact sql, why not just put that sql in a stored proc and call that from entity framework?

Comment: I definitely could do that. Does that mean there no way to generate two left joins in linq in the situation I spelled out above?

Comment: @hidden I am not 100% sure but i think you cant get exact query using EF, there is many reasons for that. 1 Data model could be complex and EF generate queries in way how it would be able to parse. Since when you use include EF will get all data which it needs to match all include Objects

Comment: Your query would work if aspnetuser had a navigation property to roles. Which it does not: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityUserRole.cs Hence, the role name is not included. Therefore, I am stuck with figuring out the left joins in linq.

Comment: @hidden What do you mean does not have property to roles _context                .Users.Include(u=>u.Roles) i just tried that in my project it works

Comment: @hidden https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityUser.cs

Comment: I added a picture showing the navigational properties is not there to get the role name. Can you let me see your intellisense showing the role name?

Comment: @hidden Now i see your problem. I have updated my answer

Comment: Thank for trying so hard to help me. I almost want to give you the 100 reward for your effort. IdentityUser<Tkey> does not have the implementation that you suggest. That is probably correct for asp.net identity 2.0 https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore/IdentityUser.cs. I will leave the question open until asp.net team fixes the issue and definitely upvote you then.

Comment: @hidden What is stopping you to override  public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole<TKey>> Roles { get; } = new List<IdentityUserRole<TKey>>(); ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around that generates the data with a very bad query. It generate a series of calls to the database that does yield the same result set. However, it is definitely not the best query for the job. I am still waiting for RC2 and I will update the answer.

```
 var query = (
                           //INNER JOIN 
                           from a in _dbCtx.AppUser
                           join b in _dbCtx.Users
                           on a.AspNetUserId equals b.Id

                           from c in _dbCtx.UserRoles
                           .Where(x => b!=null && x.UserId == b.Id)
                           .DefaultIfEmpty()

                           from d in _dbCtx.Roles
                             .Where(x => a !=null &&  x.Id == a.RoleId)
                             .DefaultIfEmpty()


                           select new
                           {
                               AppUserId = a.AppUserId,
                              Email = b.Email,
                              FirstName = a.FirstName,
                               MiddleName = a.MiddleName,
                               LastName = a.LastName,
                               IsInternal = a.IsInternal,
                               AspNetUserId = a.AspNetUserId,
                               PictureLink = a.PictureLink,
                               SignatureLink = a.SignatureLink,
                               PhoneNumber = a.PhoneNumber,
                               Extension = a.Extension,
                               FaxNumber = a.FaxNumber,
                               MobileNumber = a.MobileNumber,
                               Skype = a.Skype,
                               Role = d.Name != null ? string.Empty :d.Name ,
                               SupervisorId = a.SupervisorId,
                               BackUpId = a.BackUpId,
                               HasAutoAssignClaims = a.HasAutoAssignClaims,
                               IsActive = a.IsActive

                           }).ToList();
```